# Mocking requests for multiple tests cause side effect

Tags: clojure, leiningen, ring

I've created 2 "functional" tests for my API and when I run all the tests at once with `lein test` the requests from one test are propagated in the next test cases.
I'm wondering if there's a way to unmock or undo the requests after running a deftest.

I'm using `ring/ring-mock`, mocking the request with `ring.mock.request/mock`, and I'm running the tests with `leingein`

file1.clj

```
(deftest some-test
  (testing ""
    (app (-> (mock/request :post "/some-endpoint")
    (mock/content-type "application/json")
    (mock/body (cheshire/generate-string {:some "value"}))))
```

file2.clj

```
(deftest some-other-test-file
  (testing ""
    (let [response (app (-> (mock/request :get "/some-endpoint"))]
        ; response has {:some "value"}
)))
```

Comment: Did you check https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-redefs ? for mocking

Comment: Yes. But since it's a functional test, the variables that I'm redefining when I post something for example aren't available from my test file with `with-redefs`.

Comment: Can you add sample code to show the question?

Comment: @AlanThompson is the pseudo-code clear enough?

Comment: keep in mind that with-redefs us strictly unsuited to running tests in parallel. it is not thread safe. if you want to use it, you need to make sure it's usted so it wraps all the tests that will run in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use [Clojure test fixtures](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.test/use-fixtures).   These allow you to wrap your tests (either individually or as a group) with a setup function called before testing and a cleanup function called after testing.

Here is an example [from ClojureDocs.com](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.test/use-fixtures)

```
; See https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.test-api.html for details

; my-test-fixture will be passed a fn that will call all your tests 
; (e.g. test-using-db).  Here you perform any required setup 
; (e.g. create-db), then call the passed function f, then perform 
; any required teardown (e.g. destroy-db).
(defn my-test-fixture [f]
        (create-db)
        (f)
        (destroy-db))

; Here we register my-test-fixture to be called once, wrapping ALL tests 
; in the namespace
(use-fixtures :once my-test-fixture)

; This is a regular test function, which is to be wrapped using my-test-fixture
(deftest test-using-db
  (is ... 
))
```

Comment: I got your point. The thing is I'm trying to isolate the changes in my tests, instead of doing and undoing it manually. But I'll try to use the fixtures.

Comment: @bpereira without more information about what sort of state you're tracking and trying to "keep isolated" there isn't really a better answer than what Alan's said. My guess from your response is that your experience is working with test suites that "magically" take care of isolation for you, but if you were to look under the hood you'd find they're doing exactly what Alan recommends here.